# How to refresh data continuously while on page in Vue 3?

Tags: vuejs3

In order to display a status while on a page in Vue 3, I need to continuously refresh some data.

This works with

```js
onMounted(async () => {
    getStatus()
})

async function getStatus() {
   // load data
   // have a delay
   getStatus()

}
```

But after navigating away from page, `getStatus()` keeps getting called.

One solution would be to set a variable on `onMounted/onBeforeUnmount` and check it before recursively calling `getStatus()`. This seems cumbersome. Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple timer with `setTimeout` and destroy it when you navigate away:

```js
data()
{
  return {
    timer: null,
  }
},
created()
{
  this.timer = setTimeout(this.getStatus, 1);
},
beforeUnmount()
{
  if(this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer);
},
methods:
{
  getStatus()
  {
    this.timer = null;
    // load data
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.getStatus, 1000); // set the required delay
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivo, but I'm looking for a simpler solution which doesn't involve `onBeforeUnmount`

Comment: You can add a check inside `getStatus` for the current route - if it is still the same then you call `getStatus` again, if it is not - then you stop calling it.

Comment: Good idea. But then, when coming back to page, `getStatus` will still get called from the old page visit, and start to get called again from the new page visit.

Comment: I guess there's no solution without `onBeforeUnmount` to cleanup

Comment: If the route is not `/myRoute` at the time when the check inside `getStatus` runs - then `getStatus` will not be called. The next time you visit `/myRoute` - the `onMounted` hook will trigger and `getStatus` will start again, until you navigate away from `/myRoute`. And what is so difficult or so complex in using `onBeforeUnmounted` ? If you were using events instead - you would still subscribe for the event(s) in `onCreated` and unsubscribe in `onBeforeUnmount`. If you do not unsubscribe in `onBeforeUnmount` - event handler will still execute even if the component is destroyed.